# Extracting common values from two columns which exists in different rows using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am using the apache poi for reading and writing values to excel file with java. Now suppose I have three columns and three rows, i have values as

```
{row1, column1} = data1
{row1, column2} = data1
{row2, column1} = data2
{row2, column2} = data4
{row3, column1} = data3
{row3, column2} = data2
```

Now, I have stored all these values in two strings 'a' and 'b' for column 1 and column 2 respectively. I need to output which are common in both columns with following code:

```
for(int i=2; i<=rows_count;i++)
    {

        String a = datatable1.getCellData("temp", 1, i );
        //System.out.println("a is " + a);
        String b = datatable1.getCellData("temp", 3, i);
        //System.out.println("b is " + b);

        if(a.equals(b))
        {
        System.out.println(b);
        }

    }
```

With this I am getting the output as 'data1' only but not 'data2' as these are in different rows. Any ideas how to resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: Why the above code is not working, any ideas? i converted it to Arraylist too, still getting the same result..Please help

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking is how to report all cell values which appear more than once in a section of the file. Assuming so, simplest thing is probably

```
Set<String> alreadySeen = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<String>();
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();

// Update these as per your requirements
int firstRowToCheck = 0;
int lastRowToCheck = Math.min(3, sheet.getLastRowNum());
int firstColumnToCheck = 0;
int lastColumnToCheck = 1;

// Loop over the rows and cells of interest
for (int rn=firstRowToCheck; rn <= lastRowToCheck; rn++) {
    Row r = sheet.getRow(rn);
    if (r == null) {
       // No cells in this row have any values
    } else {
       for (int cn=firstColumnToCheck; cn <= lastColumnToCheck; cn++) {
           Cell c = row.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
           if (c == null) {
               // No value for this cell
           } else {
               String value = fmt.formatCellValue(c);
               if (alreadySeen.contains(value)) {
                  // Duplicate!
                  duplicates.put(value);
               } else {
                  // First time this has been seen
                  alreadySeen.put(value);
               }
           }
       }
    }
}

// Report duplicates
for (String dup : duplicates) {
    System.out.println(dup);
}
```

Comment: Not working how? In what way? What error? What behaviour?